# why -1 is necessary to index error in python list index out of range for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

```
index error: list out of range
```

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i] == lst[i+1]:
         print(True)
```

if we use `len(lst) - 1` it works 
why?

Comment: Please rewrite your question in a more understandable way. You cannot begin a post with "error", please give context etc. before. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`len(lst)` is 4, so your `range` object will be over 0, 1, 2, and 3.  When `i` is 3, `lst[i+1]` will be `lst[4]`.  4 is not a valid index for `lst`.

If you do `range(len(lst)-1)`, however, you'll be running over just 0, 1, and 2.  Therefore, when `i` is 2, you'll be comparing the last two elements of the array, namely, `lst[2]` and `lst[3]`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because python list are indexed from `0` to `n-1` where `n` is the number of elements present in the list.

1. The `range(len(lst))` will loop from 0 to `len(lst)-1`. But you are also using `lst[i+1]` inside the loop which makes your array access the index out of range on the last iteration and hence the error. For eg. if your list length is 4, then on the last iteration, `i` will be 3 and you are accessing `lst[i+1]`, which is `lst[4]` which is out of bounds of the list.
2. When you use `range(len(lst)-1)`, you are only iterating from 0 to `len(lst)-1` which means that even on the last iteration, you are only accessing upto `lst[len(lst)-1]`, that is the last index of the last and never accessing the out of bound index. Hence, this one is the correct way to iterate over the loop in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Assume this is your list:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now when you do:

```
for i in range(len(lst))
```

The range will give you the values for `i` as:

```
0, 1, 2, 3
```

In this statement, when `i` is `3`, you also try to access the index `4`, which doesn't exist:

```
if lst[i] == lst[i+1]:
```

Hence, the exception.